# Is there a better way to get Stripe total charge amount?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I am currently getting the total charge amount from Stripe as below.  However I have to retrieve all charges in sets of 100 and it is very inefficient and slow.

It currently takes 40 seconds to run from a firebase cloud function.

Is there a way I can make a single call for this?

```
export async function getStatistics(): Promise<any> {
  try {
    let count = 100;
    let totalCount = 0;
    let totalCharge = 0;
    let allCharges = [];
    let lastCharge = null;
    let charges;

    while (count === 100) {
      if (!lastCharge) {
        charges = await stripe.charges.list({ limit: 100});
      } else {
        charges = await stripe.charges.list({ starting_after: lastCharge.id, limit: 100});
      }
      count = charges.data.length;
      lastCharge = charges.data[count - 1];
      totalCount = totalCount + count;
      allCharges = allCharges.concat(charges.data);
      if (totalCount > 2000) {
        // failsafe
        break;
      }
    }

    for (const charge of allCharges) {
      totalCharge = totalCharge + charge.amount;
    }

    return { totalCharge: totalCharge, totalCount: totalCount };
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    throw err;
  }
}
```

Comment: Store the charges on your end, so you don't have to fetch the entire list every time.

Comment: Good suggestion.  However there is currently an issue with the running firebase cloud functions reliably so my aggregates are never correct, I was looking to to get the data directly from Stripe to counter this.  I will likely just run this Stripe function once a day.

Comment: You might look into webhooks for charges.

Comment: Oh good call I didn't think of that.  I have used them before for other purposes.  That would work nicely.